# How to compare an element of array with all the elements of another array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, codeblocks

I have 2 arrays :  a [ ] = {1,2,3,4,5,6} and b [ ] = {1,2,6}. How can I compare all elements from array a with all from array b. For example, I compare the first element from a with all elements from b, and if they are not equal, it's displayed and continue to check. So after all I need to get c [ ] = {3,4,5}.

Please help me.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
        if(sf[i].r != temp[j].r)
        {
            cout<<sf[i].r<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

Where sf[ ] .r = {1,2,2,2,3,5,6,6,7,8,8} and temp[ ].r = { 1,3,5,7} . Output must be {2,2,2,6,6,8,8}.

Comment: You described the algorithm pretty well. What prevents you from implementing it?

Comment: Check out `std::set_difference`

Comment: @Ferrrnando, you might show your code, btw.

Comment: @vahancho check the update

Comment: @Ferrrnando, it's a little bit confusing. Is `sf[ ] .r` refers to an array or an element in the array? What is `r`?

Comment: @vahancho its a member of structure

Comment: @Ferrrnando, your code looks good, but the problem is that you print out the "different" element as soon as they are not equal. Instead, you must compare each element from `sf` to **all** elements in `temp`. I.e. if you have [1, 2, 3] and [3, 2, 1], you take the first `1`, and compare it with `3` (don't print it yet), `2` (don't print) and `1` from the second array.

Comment: @vahancho can you please tell how can i create a vector that storage a member structure

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `std::vector<int>` to build up your results, something like:

```
std::vector<int> set_difference;
for (int elem_a : a)
{
    if (std::find(std::begin(b), std::end(b), elem_a) == std::end(b))
    {
        set_difference.push_back(elem_a);
    }
}
```

Comment: when i launch it, it says that begin and is not a member of std. What can i do?

Comment: @Ferrrnando `#include <iterator>` you'll also need `#include <algorithm>` for `std::find` and `#include <vector>` for `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int b[] = { 1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 9 };
std::vector<int> c;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(b); j++)
    {
        if (a[i] == b[j])
            std::cout << a[i] << " equals " << b[j] << std::endl;
        else
        {
            std::cout << a[i] << "not equals " << b[j] << std::endl;
            c.push_back(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it compares first elem. from a with all from b , but after that , it start to compares first elem. of a with others elem of a.